# Can forcats::as_factor return an ordered factor?

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

Can `as_factor` from `forcats` return an ordered factor? It seems like a missing feature if not although I haven't seen it reported as an issue on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats/issues).

I have tried:

```
y <- forcats::as_factor(c("a", "z", "g"), ordered = TRUE)
is.ordered(y)
# FALSE
```

If I can't then is there any potential danger in doing:

```
y <- ordered(forcats::as_factor(c("a", "z", "g")))
```

Or would it be better to do:

```
y <- factor(c("a", "z", "g"), levels = unique(c("a", "z", "g")), ordered = TRUE))
```

Comment: While `forcats:::as_factor.character` calls `fct_inorder`, which does support an `ordered=` argument, it seems to be hardcoded as `fct_inorder(x)` so that no matter what you pass in, it ain't going to be ordered. It might be a bug as `fct_inorder(x,...)` instead seems to allow the extra `ordered=`

Answer (score 3):

It appears this indeed is an unexpected behavior. `forcats::as_factor` is forcing it to be ordered as they appear, but somehow does not set the flag. But combining it with `base::factor`, it's not required to explicitly specify the ordering, just setting the flag seems to work fine.

```
y <- forcats::as_factor(c("a", "z", "g"))
y
[1] a z g
Levels: a z g

is.ordered(y)
[1] FALSE

k <- factor(y, c("a","z","g"), ordered = TRUE)
k
[1] a z g
Levels: a < z < g

is.ordered(k)
[1] TRUE

k2 <- factor( y, ordered = TRUE)
k2
[1] a z g
Levels: a < z < g

is.ordered(k2)
[1] TRUE

k3 <- factor(forcats::as_factor(c("a","g","z")), ordered = TRUE)
k3
[1] a g z
Levels: a < g < z

is.ordered(k3)
[1] TRUE
```